# Вопрос по расположению блоков - наползают друг на друга

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Нужно сделать так, чтобы в зависимости от разрешения экрана, блоки (могут быть разной высоты в зависимости от содержимого) выстраивались все время в аккуратные ряды друг за другом, и не наползали друг на друга как сейчас. Убрать `float` не помогает.

```css
.member {
 display:inline-block;
 width:160px;
 font-size:14px;
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="member">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x188">
  <h4>Заголовок</h4>
  <p>Описание</p>
  <p>телефон</p>
  <p>факс</p>
  <a href="mailto:email">email</a> 
</div>
<div class="member">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x188">
  <h4>Заголовок</h4>
  <p>Описание бла-бла-бла бла-бла-бла</p>
  <p>телефон</p>
  <p>факс</p>
  <a href="mailto:email">email</a> 
</div>
<div class="member">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x188">
  <h4>Заголовок</h4>
  <p>Описание</p>
  <p>телефон</p>
  <p>факс</p>
  <a href="mailto:email">email</a> 
</div>
<div class="member">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x188">
  <h4>Заголовок</h4>
  <p>Описание бла-бла-бла</p>
  <p>телефон</p>
  <p>факс</p>
  <a href="mailto:email">email</a> 
</div>
<div class="member">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x188">
  <h4>Заголовок</h4>
  <p>Описание бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла</p>
  <p>телефон</p>
  <a href="mailto:email">email</a> 
</div>
<div class="member">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x188">
  <h4>Заголовок</h4>
  <p>Описание</p>
  <p>телефон</p>
  <p>факс</p>
  <a href="mailto:email">email</a> 
</div>
<div class="member">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x188">
  <h4>Заголовок</h4>
  <p>Описание</p>
  <p>телефон</p>
  <a href="mailto:email">email</a> 
</div>
<div class="member">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x188">
  <h4>Заголовок</h4>
  <p>Описание</p>
  <p>телефон</p>
  <p>факс</p>
  <a href="mailto:email">email</a> 
</div>
<div class="member">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x188">
  <h4>Заголовок</h4>
  <p>Описание</p>
  <p>телефон</p>
  <p>факс</p>
  <a href="mailto:email">email</a> 
</div>
<div class="member">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x188">
  <h4>Заголовок</h4>
  <p>Описание</p>
  <p>телефон</p>
  <a href="mailto:email">email</a> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение - [здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/shrprug4/2/)

```css
.member {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 14px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="member">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x188">
  <h4>Заголовок</h4>
  <p>Описание</p>
  <p>телефон</p>
  <p>факс</p>
  <a href="mailto:email">email</a> 
</div>
<div class="member">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x188">
  <h4>Заголовок</h4>
  <p>Описание бла-бла-бла бла-бла-бла</p>
  <p>телефон</p>
  <p>факс</p>
  <a href="mailto:email">email</a> 
</div>
<div class="member">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x188">
  <h4>Заголовок</h4>
  <p>Описание</p>
  <p>телефон</p>
  <p>факс</p>
  <a href="mailto:email">email</a> 
</div>
<div class="member">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x188">
  <h4>Заголовок</h4>
  <p>Описание бла-бла-бла</p>
  <p>телефон</p>
  <p>факс</p>
  <a href="mailto:email">email</a> 
</div>
<div class="member">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x188">
  <h4>Заголовок</h4>
  <p>Описание бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла</p>
  <p>телефон</p>
  <a href="mailto:email">email</a> 
</div>
<div class="member">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x188">
  <h4>Заголовок</h4>
  <p>Описание</p>
  <p>телефон</p>
  <p>факс</p>
  <a href="mailto:email">email</a> 
</div>
<div class="member">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x188">
  <h4>Заголовок</h4>
  <p>Описание</p>
  <p>телефон</p>
  <a href="mailto:email">email</a> 
</div>
<div class="member">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x188">
  <h4>Заголовок</h4>
  <p>Описание</p>
  <p>телефон</p>
  <p>факс</p>
  <a href="mailto:email">email</a> 
</div>
<div class="member">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x188">
  <h4>Заголовок</h4>
  <p>Описание</p>
  <p>телефон</p>
  <p>факс</p>
  <a href="mailto:email">email</a> 
</div>
<div class="member">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x188">
  <h4>Заголовок</h4>
  <p>Описание</p>
  <p>телефон</p>
  <a href="mailto:email">email</a> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ширина member должна быть ровна ширине изображений.И исходя из того,сколько блоков у вас должно быть в 1 ряду-прописывайте ширину родительскому блоку.
Например.Вы хотите, что бы блоки member были по 5 штук в ряд.Значит ширину каждого ставите 200 пикселей.И ширину родительского элемента ставите 1000 пикселей+ему же(родительскому элементу) пропишите margin:0 auto

Comment: нет-нет, сайт должен под разные разрешения адаптироваться - я об этом писал в описании, поэтому никаких заданий ширины родительскому элементу. и с чего вы взяли, что ширина member должна быть ровна ширине изображений - совсем не обязательно. посмотрите правильный ответ выше - там все верно